# How do I make objects jump back to start within a given radius of an area after a collision to a specific object?

Tags: game-engine, physics, logic-bricks

How do I make objects jump back to start within a given radius of an area after a collision to a specific object?

What I am trying to do is make a rotating snow plain (who's texture is invisible) jump back up to its initial Z position and choose a random X, Y position within a specific radius. I would like for it to do this after colliding with a specific plain object that's been placed under the terrain.

[out of game snow]

[image]

[Edited version to better show what I need]
[[image]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adomF.png)

Answer (score 0):

While I wasn't exactly able to get the effect I wanted using this method I found that I could take a UV sphere, or possibly an Ico-Sphere and set the texture to an alpha clip while also simply rotating them on the Z and X(y depending on which way you want it to rotate) directions. This gives a nice looking snow effect, and might even work with dust. The shape must always be close to the ground in order for it to give a desired effect. [image]